# Just one row getting updated in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Below is my model code and when i try to update it just updates the first row and not the others.I also tried with update_batch but it returns a database error page.

```
   My Model Code:
      foreach ($ingredients as $item) {
        //  $this->sma->print_arrays($item);
       if($item['id']){
       $this->db->where('id', $item['id']);
       $this->db->update('items', $item);
       // }
       return true;
     }
```

My Array:(Ingredients)

```
  Array
   (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 16
        [quantity] => 76
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 92
        [quantity] => 97
    )

  )
```

Your help will be aprreciated

Comment: due to return true; inside loop.

Comment: remove return statement.

Comment: @MubasharIqbal Ohh !! thanks a lot.. that was really quick, you made my work easier ;)

Comment: use `update_batch('items', $ingredients, 'id');` to update all at a time. And all array should be identical.

Comment: Any idea why the return true was causing the issue, am new to php so a brief explanation will make me understand better.

Comment: because when you use true then program execution stop immediately for that scope. So in foreach loop you are using return in loop so on first iteration it will back to controller. Here is manual for [return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use `update_batch` to update a set of data.

```
$data = array(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 16
        [quantity] => 76
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 92
        [quantity] => 97
    )
);

$this->db->update_batch('tableName', $data, 'id');
```

Comment: I just removed the return inside the loop and it worked..Thanks